# How do I find the items immediately before and after a specific one in an ordered array, using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting

I have an array of 'questions' ordered according to their number of votes, and want to show the question immediately before and immediately following the currently-selected question.

Let's say the currently-selected question is stored in the variable @question, and I'm showing a list of other questions associated with the same user. This code orders that list according to number of votes:

```
questions = Question.find(:all, :conditions => {:user => @question.user}).sort { |q1,q2| q2.votes.length <=> q1.votes.length}
```

Now how do I pick out just the question before and the question after @question in that list?

Comment: What you do here smells very bad! If you have n questions, you need to do n+1 queries to obtain questions array. Please learn what is counter cache - http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column - and sort your question using that column: `Question.find(:all, :conditions => {:user => @question.user}, :order => 'votes_count DESC')`. Alternatively, you could join your votes model and add a column with `count()` SQL function and sort by it.

Comment: Thanks, I watched the railscast and that does look like a better way to sort the questions by number of votes. But doesn't quite solve the problem, I still don't know how to locate my current question in that ordered array and just display the questions before and after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer. I figured you guys would get the gist from the first post but here is a more elaborated example.

Can't you do something simple like:

```
@questions = user.questions.sort_by{ |q| -q.votes.length }
current_question_index = @questions.index(@question)
@prev_question = @questions[current_question_index-1]
@next_question = @questions[current_question_index+1]
```

It's more lines but just uses simple array manipulation

Comment: Do you need something more than this, as in do you need an efficient database query to pick only those out? If you can give the nature of the data maybe I can give you a specific query to get that information...? Usually you can do something like subtracting the number of votes from the number of your current question, and then wrap that in a select which selects the one with the smallest of the positive results or greatest of the negatives.

Comment: This fails when removing records, you eventually could get a set of consecutive ID's  like these [1,2,4,6,10,11] making current_question.id+-1 fail.

Comment: Wouldn't this answer just sort by the question id, rather than the number of votes?

Comment: Worked! I'm a ruby-nuby, so thanks for walking me through it.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to time stamps.

```
prev = Question.first(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", @question.created_at], :order => "created_at DESC")
prev = Question.first(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", @question.created_at], :order => "created_at ASC")
```